# Calling a class method with local variable as parameter

Tags: ruby

I want to pass a string in a variable from a method to another class. I have this code:

```
class A
  def method_a
    variable = "some string"
    B.method_b(variable)
  end
end

class B
  def self.method_b(parameter)
    puts parameter
  end
end
```

This code generates the following error:

```
Undefined local variable or method `variable`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe `methodB(variable)`? Also, please, edit your class names. Did you include `class B` into `class A`?

Comment: Remember Ruby is unusually case aware. This should be `class A` and `class B`, as classnames follow the `CaseFirstFormat`. Method names should be all lowercase and underscored, so `method_b` for example.

Comment: There's no reference to `randomName` in your code at all, so what line in this code produced the error?

Comment: @tadman sorry for that, I edited the questions, the error it like this: "Undefined local variable or method `variable' "

Comment: This code works for me.

Comment: It cannot be reproduced in two senses. If you run your code as is, nothing happens, as it does not call any method. If you add a method call like `A.new.method_a`, which you were too lazy to do, then it still does not raise an error.

Comment: https://repl.it/BoWp

Answer (score 2):

What you've defined here is an instance method, one that can only operate on an instance of B:

```
class B
  def self.class_only(v)
    puts "Class: #{v}"
  end

  def instance_only(v)
    puts "Instance: #{v}"
  end
end
```

The `class_only` method does not require an instance:

```
B.class_only(variable)
```

The `instance_only` method must operate on an instance:

```
b = B.new
b.instance_only(variable)
```

Now anything the B method is given via arguments is valid, and any local or instance variables on the A side are things you can supply to the call. There's no scope issues here because you're explicitly passing them over.

For example:

```
class A
  def test
    variable = SecureRandom.hex(6)
    B.class_only(variable)
  end
end

A.new.test
```

Comment: suppose I defined like self.method_b, I have the same error, what is happening??

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't have problems, so you must be running something different than that. Can you update it to better reflect the issue you're having? I can't reproduce it with what you have. Example code [pasted here](http://codepad.org/Kx3y7sDi).